# Clearing boost::array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, boost-asio

I'm using a boost array as buffer for the content I get from the async_read of the boost::asio.

After reading I want to clear/reset the buffer for the next read. Please tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Do you want the clear() functionality of std::vector? If not, what is that you expect array clear() to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to clean each reading, just use the amount of bytes read
`buffer(array, bytes_readed)`

In case you still want, you can use the assign method
`array.assign(0);`

Comment: Hm, current g++ compiler does not seem to support the `assign` method :(

Comment: your_array.assign( the_default_value_of_array_elem ); is the only way you can fill the array with the default value of your choice. assign() does this: std::fill_n(begin(), N, value) {quoting from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/array.html#id426226-bb}